# Is there a way to use create() method on laravel eloquent model where data will call there corresponding set{field}Attribute method?

Tags: eloquent

I'm trying to use create() method to create an object say 'user' from laravel-excel Import class say 'UserImport'. In the collection method, I grabbed the first row as the properties of the user and every cell in the subsequent row bears the data for the user on each row.
Using the create method will ensure that field that is not in my fillable will not be inserted as fields are dynamically gotten. I need the create method to use setGenderAttribute defined on the User model so as to transform 'male', 'm' in the excel gender column to constant User::GENDER_MALE and 'female', 'f' to constant User::GENDER_FEMALE.

```
public function collection(Collection $rows)
{        
    $keys = [];
    // Extract spreadsheet head
    foreach ($rows[0] as $key) {
        $keys[] = Str::snake($key);
    }
    $j = 0;
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        // Offset the head from the data set
        if ($j == 0) {
            $j++;
            continue;
        }
        // get data from each row
        $data = [];
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($keys as $key) {
            $data[$key] = $row[$i];
            $i++;
        }
        // Create user from each row
        $user = User::create($data);
        event(new MemberAdded($user));            
    }
}
```

It throws the following error integer value: 'male' for column `users`.`gender`

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten to the answer. Laravel create method on eloquent actually call all the set{field}Attribute before actually doing database insertion. The problem was in one of the 'set' method. There was a bug in it and laravel fall back to the original field which was a string whose column was defined as integer in the database table schema.